# Check associative string array values

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following string array

```
$array = array(
    "key" => "zhcdde,hzccd,eezhg"
);
```

I want to get the values, split them with ',' and count the equal letters. For example only "z" and "h" are equal, since these are the only characters that occur in every string composition. I tried a few things like this

```
$equalLetters = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $splitWords) {
    $words = explode(",", $splitWords);
    for ($letter = 0; $letter < strlen($words[0]); $letter++) {
        if ($words[0][$letter] == $words[1][$letter] || $words[0][$letter] == $words[2][$letter] || $words[1][$letter] == $words[2][$letter]) {
            $equalLetters++;
        }
    }
}
echo $equalLetters;
```

Without success. Can you guys help me ?

Answer (score 3):

Unclear for me how the associative array factors into it, but here's how you can get the common letters in your strings:

```
<?php
    $string = 'zhcdde,hzccd,eezhg';
    $words = explode(',', $string);
    $letters = array_map('str_split', $words);
    $common = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $letters);

    var_dump($common);
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "z"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "h"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is there a way in which i can do the same with for loops ?

Comment: There is, but I already provided a working answer and won't provide a second one that will end up being three times as verbose.